# Representing JSON data from Java object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse some json data and represent it in a way that is both easy readable and is valid for highcharts.

From the back end I am getting the following

```
{
    "AVN-LON-TEST-A": {
        "mapOfVersionAndCount": {
            "Chrome": {
                "versionAndCountMap": {
                    "61": 2,
                    "62": 2,
                    "63": 2
                }
            },
            "Firefox": {
                "versionAndCountMap": {
                    "57": 2
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "AVN-LON-TEST-B": {
        "mapOfVersionAndCount": {
            "Chrome": {
                "versionAndCountMap": {
                    "63": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to represent the data above as the following

```
  [{
        name: 'Chrome - 64',
        data: [2,0]
    },
        name: 'Chrome - 63',
        data: [1,2]
    }, {
        name: 'FireFox',
        data: [0,1]
    }]
```

Here is my code

```
 var ossIds = Object.keys(data);
    var browserAndVersions = [];

    ossIds.forEach(function (ossId) {
        var browserNames = data[ossId];

        Object.keys(browserNames.mapOfVersionAndCount).forEach(function(browserName) {
            var versionAndCountMap = browserNames.mapOfVersionAndCount[browserName];
            var versions = Object.keys(versionAndCountMap.versionAndCountMap);
            var counts = Object.values(versionAndCountMap.versionAndCountMap);

            versions.forEach(function(version) {
                var nameAndVersion = browserName + "-" + version;
                browserAndVersions.push({name: nameAndVersion, data: counts});
            });
        });
    });
```

The above code seems to print out the following

```
[{
    "name": "Chrome-61",
    "data": [2, 2, 2]
}, {
    "name": "Chrome-62",
    "data": [2, 2, 2]
}, {
    "name": "Chrome-63",
    "data": [2, 2, 2]
}, {
    "name": "Firefox-57",
    "data": [2]
}, {
    "name": "Chrome-63",
    "data": [1]
}]
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Any help would be much appreciated

Update:
within data: [2, 2]
each 2 is the category so

AVN-LON-TEST-A
2

AVN-LON-TEST-B
2

Hope that makes sense

Comment: In your question the demo object has two properties with the same name, `AVN-LON-TEST-A`, not sure if that's a typo, but you can't have two properties with the same name in a JS object (one overwrites the other).

Comment: yeah my bad, that was a typo, thanks

Comment: Please can you explain how the first JSON object would map to your representation? What does [2,0] represent? There is no Chrome 64 in the original JSON?

Comment: So within the array [2,0] is the category i.e each object so `AVN-LON-TEST-A` is 2 while `AVN-LON-TEST-B` is 0

Comment: So, what is `1` in `[1,2]` (under 'Chrome - 63')?

Comment: So `1` is `AVN-LON-TEST-A ` while `2` is `AVN-LON-TEST-B`

Comment: Please update the question with the expected result. As there is no Chrome 64 in the original JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, each time you see Object.keys, usually means that data would have been better represented as an array rather than an object.  However, this should work.  It generates an object with the browser names/versions as keys (so it's easy to check if a browser/version combo exists), and then flattens it to an array at the end.

```js
var data = {
    "AVN-LON-TEST-A": {
        "mapOfVersionAndCount": {
            "Chrome": {
                "versionAndCountMap": {
                    "61": 2,
                    "62": 2,
                    "63": 2
                }
            },
            "Firefox": {
                "versionAndCountMap": {
                    "57": 2
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "AVN-LON-TEST-B": {
        "mapOfVersionAndCount": {
            "Chrome": {
                "versionAndCountMap": {
                    "63": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var obj = {};
var len = Object.keys(data).length;
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (name, i) {
  Object.keys(data[name].mapOfVersionAndCount).forEach(function (browser) {
    Object.keys(data[name].mapOfVersionAndCount[browser].versionAndCountMap).forEach(function (version) {
      var id = browser + "-" + version;
      if (!obj[id]) obj[id] = Array(len).fill(0);
      obj[id][i] += data[name].mapOfVersionAndCount[browser].versionAndCountMap[version];
    });
  });
});

var out = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
  return {name: key, data: obj[key]};
});
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thanks James, this is what I as looking for. It's quite complex code for me, but i'll step through each line and try to understand even thought you've explained it pretty well.